# How can I find my files in GCP AI Notebook?

Tags: gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I have been working on a GCP AI Notebook for the past couple of weeks when I got '524 error'. I followed the troubleshooting instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/troubleshooting). I connected to the notebook instance via ssh and restarted the Jupyter service. I am now able to open JupyterLab but I can't find any of my work!! [Here is the JupyterLab screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSyvz.png). I searched for the files using Terminal in JupyterLab as well as the Cloud Shell but nothing. It looks as if my instance had been wiped clean.
Please help, I lost all my code I have been working on for the past couple of weeks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Terminal output, seems to be you are using a Container based instance.
This means that you have a base OS and a Docker instance running JupyterLab service on top. I will be interested in knowing what Docker instance is that you are running. Is this a [Deep Learning Container](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/deep-learning-containers)?

1. By default (If using Deep Learning Containers) files are stored in /home/jupyter and this folder is mapped to local disk so you can see if there is something inside jupyter. Do you have something there?
2. You can SSH into Jupyter instance and verify which is your container and parameters passed.

```
sudo docker ps --no-trunc
```